# Unmap ctrl+space in Sublime Text 3

Tags: macos, sublimetext3

On OS X, I have ctrl+space mapped systemwide to "Help...Search". However, in Sublime Text 3, the default for ctrl+space is auto-complete. In Sublime Text 2, I was able to edit the default keymap and just delete it, but it seems like you can no longer edit the default keymap anymore.

Is there any way in Sublime Text 3 to "undefine" a keymap so that Sublime will allow the operating system wide shortcut to take effect instead?

Comment: have you tried setting your custom keymap to have `ctrl+space` map to nothing? `{ "keys": ["ctrl+space"], "command": "" }`. Also, you should be able to open the appropriate `.sublime-keymap` file in **ST2** and edit it...

Comment: @MattDMo Just tried setting it to nothing, and, alas, it doesn't work. ST3 (unlike ST2) does not expose the default keymap as a file in the filesystem, so I can't just open it and edit it. If I open it inside of ST3, it's in a ready-only buffer.

Comment: @LorinHochstein @MattDMo Setting it to, for example "x" works for me (was hitting `strg+q` instead of `strg+w`): `{ "keys": ["ctrl+q"], "command": "x" }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `/Applications`, left-click on `Sublime Text.app`, and select "Show Package Contents". Open `Contents/MacOS/Packages/Default.sublime-package` in [TextWrangler](http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/) (it's a free d/l if you don't have it) - it supports editing ZIP files. You should now be able to edit `Default (OSX).sublime-keymap` and save the whole package. Restart ST3 and you should be good!

Comment: Due to some weird issue in TextWrangler, I can open the file but it doesn't let me save it properly, I keep getting prompted to save a new file again. but this info is enough for me to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

1. Select menu. Sublime Text > Preferences > Key Bindings - Default
2. Default (OSX).sublime-keymap (read-only) will open.
3. Save as new file has same name to ~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/Default (not exist. create new folder).
4. Close (2)
5. Do (1) again.
6. You can edit default keymap :)

Comment: Thanks it works for me. The only thing I have to add is ~/Library is different with another Library folder which is visible to everyone. In some of Mac OSX versions like El Capitan, this folder is totally hidden. To access this folder right click on finder icon in Dock and choose  Go to folder... and then type in the appeared box ~/Library and press Enter. Then you can see the hidden library folder and do the steps which are mentioned in this post.