# How to enable OS X cmd+ctrl+space character menu in Sublime Text 2?

Tags: macos, sublimetext2, special-characters, osx-yosemite

In most OS X apps, even the Terminal which otherwise seems to lack features, cmd+ctrl+space brings up a character menu, where you can type in the name and look for special characters (e.g. greek alphabet). In Sublime Text 2 this does not come up; I just get the bell sound. I tried the trick described [Unmap ctrl+space in Sublime Text 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17413163/unmap-ctrlspace-in-sublime-text-3) of mapping the key to the empty command, but that did nothing. Anyone have an idea of how to enable the menu?

Answer (score 1):

The default shortcut for this in ST2, of course, is `alt+super+t`, but I assume you are wanting to remap this, right?

If so, I looked pretty hard on this one, unfortunately, I couldn't find much to help. It is not a default command, and even if you look inside `Packages/Default/Main.sublime-menu`, right where the "Special Characters..." line should appear, it is conspicuously absent. Logging all commands in the console using `sublime.log_commands(True)` shows nothing when I open the special characters window this way.